# Is 13 inch MacBook Pro enough with Eclipse?

Tags: macbook-pro, eclipse

I'm a Java developer and want to buy a new 2013 Retina MacBook Pro.

I'm interested in the 13 inch for portability but I'm worried it has too small display to effectively code using Eclipse.

Has anyone tried using this machine in this way? Do I have to get the 15 inch?

Comment: 13 inch would be good enough to code on using eclipse. Not much of a clutter on IDE and yet offers much efficiency in performance.

Comment: Have you actually tried it?  I'd love to benefit from a developer's experience. I appreciate it's not going to be the same as a 24 inch monitor - just want to understand if the retina makes it possible.

Comment: the retina doesn't change anything in comparaison of the "normal" display, this size stay the same, things just look sharper !